# Xcode - Localization not work when clicking "Make Localized"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization

I created a string file named "Localizable.strings" from Xcode (File > New > File > Strings File) because I want to localize my app.

My string work perfectly now. My localizable string file contains

```
"TEST_TEXT" = "Test";
```

In the code I set

```
label1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"TEST_TEXT", nil);
```

like I said it works perfectly. The label shows "Test" while the app is running.

But when I click "Make Localized" and choose English it will not work. My label will show TEST_TEXT and the file will be moved to en.lproj.

Maybe iOS don't find the file in en.lproj?

Jonathan

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator or on a device? Did you clean your project, then delete the app from the simulator/device before testing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a new strings file and NOT name it Localizable.strings

i named it Localization.strings .

then we have to use:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"TEST_TEXT", @"Localization/*(Your strings file name)*/", nil);
```

TEST_TEXT is the key from your strings file.
Localization is the name of your strings file (not named Localizable).
nil is comments that we don't need to use, thats why i'm typing nil.